# Javascript not decoding JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, decode, encode

What is the proper way to encode/decode data with JSON using PHP and Javascript

My PHP is simple:

```
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_SESSION['orl']);
```

Simple name value pairs in text, no objects or anything.

My JavaScript is

```
function checkForSeshStuff(){
    window.alert("check sesh called");
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://internal.example.com/orl_get_sesh.php",
        onload: function(response) {
            window.alert(response.responseText);
            var obj = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            window.alert(obj.count);
            if(obj.count > 1){
                document.getElementById('ajaxSeshStat').innerHTML = "<input type='button' onclick='loadLastSesh();' value='Populate "+obj.count+" Fields' />";
                document.getElementById('ajaxSeshStat').style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have a bunch of alerts for debugging, the third one which alerts the JSON count alerts "undefined" every time.

Am I using the proper mime type in my PHP? Am I parsing correctly in my JS? What's wrong?

**EDIT**
Here's the string of JSON data generated by PHP

> `{"BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_chRead":"on","BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtOfferCode":"xc","BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtFirstName1":"cx","BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtCity1":"Beverly Hills","BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtZip1":"90210","BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtMonthlyIncome1":"0","BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtOtherIncome1":"0","BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_chbCoBorrowerContactInformation":"on","BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtMonthlyIncome2":"0","BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtOtherIncome2":"0"}`

Comment: what does the alert of response.responseText show? If there's ANYTHING in there other than json, the parse will fail. e.g. php warnings.

Comment: Are you sure that `$_SESSION['orl']` has a `count` property?

Comment: @ExplosionPills `$_SESSION['orl']` is an array, so yes it does

Comment: If you use `console.log(response)` instead of alert, you can see the entire response in your browser's console, and might get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: @MarcB Added it to the question

Comment: that json's fine. what about what's received on the client side?

Comment: @Seth it's a greasmonkey script, it executes in sandbox and therefore does not log things to console. I still don't know how to properly debug this damn thing.

Comment: @MarcB How can I determine that?

Comment: `window.alert(response.responseText);`, just like you have already. or maybe `console.log`.

Comment: @Adelphia PHP arrays don't automatically have a `count` property ... maybe you should start with that.  Also note that `count` is missing from the JSON.

Comment: window.alert(this.responseText);

Comment: ooooh ok.. well then how do I get the count? @ExplosionPills

Comment: Object.keys(obj).length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your session have a count element in the array? It doesn't look like it.

Have you tried:

```
alert(obj.BodyContent_ctl00_ctl00_txtZip1)
```